# jQuery $.get() Memory Usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is the jQuery method that I have at my webpage, it refreshes a image every 5 seconds by loading the same page and replacing the image.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
        $.get('default.aspx', function (data) {
            var page = data;
            var image = $(page).find("img");
            var fecha = $(page).find("div #fecha");


            $("#Chart1").attr("src", image.attr("src"));
            $("#fecha").text(fecha.text());                    
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

I saw that everytime it loads the img, the data get stored somewhere in the browser and it doesnt cleans.. And when I open the task manager, I can see the memory usage growing up..

and heres a screenshot of the image axd..

Should I worry about freeing memory? Or everything is working as its supposed to..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the browser is just caching the images, but they are being cleaned eventually.

Answer (score 3):

why not reload the image by using just the url and not fetch the whole page that gets the url? if you want to prevent cache, either set the image not to cache via server headers, or use [cachebusting](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/)

```
var img = document.getElementById('Chart1');          //use plain JS since it's just an ID
var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
    var rand = "?"+(Math.random()*10000000000000000);  //cache busting method
    img.src = "path_to_image"+rand                     //set src using busted url
}, 5000);
```

this will still eat up disk space since each busted images is treated like a different image. if it were cached, you'd be using stale images. but at least you are not loading the whole page again an again.

Comment: the problem is that the images are dynamic.. they are random number like this /ChartImg.axd?i=chart_0_0.png&amp;g=1f126b056fe649f18be923a374668d9d

Answer (score 0):

Use $post instead of $get. IE often cash GET request data.

Answer (score 0):

There is just one img#Chart1 in your page, so there is only one image uses memory.
Others would just in the browser's cache.

But I don't think that default.aspx return in html format, 
it should return data in json like:

```
{
    imageUrl: "http://example.com/a.jpg",
    fetcha: "some text"
}
```